# show that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the cofinite topology, every open set is both connected and path connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I want to show that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the cofinite topology, every open  set is both connected and path connected.

To do so, I thought of using the following result : for a finite set S, the set $\mathbb{R}^2/S$ is connected in the Euclidean topology.

It gives us that $\forall C \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ open with the cofinite topology ( ie $\mathbb{R}^2 / C $ is finite) ,  $\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{R}^2 / C) = C $ is connected in the Euclidean topology.

But then I don't see how we could link it with connectedness in the cofinite topology.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Connected: the whole space is not a disjoint union of two proper open subsets.  Let's say $\mathbb R^2=X\sqcup Y$, where $X, Y$ are both open (in cofinite topology). What would you conclude?

Comment: we can say that $\emptyset = \mathbb{R}^2 / X \cap \mathbb{R}^2 / Y$ which is possible only if X or Y is empty. But what about path connectedness? @StinkingBishop

Comment: Let $X$ be a nonempty set with a finite complement. It is path-connected in the "ordinary" $\mathbb R^2$ topology, i.e. you can connect any two points $x,y\in X$ via a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to X, f(0)=x, f(1)=y$. Does this map stay continuous if you now switch from "ordinary" topology to the cofinite topology?

Comment: @StinkingBishop It is not quite obvious why the map should stay continuous with the cofinite topology. Could you please be more explicit ?

Comment: Recall that a map is continuous if the inverse image of every open set in the co-domain is open in the domain topological space.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you :)

Comment: Any injective $f:]0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ with the co-finite topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is continuous because if $C\subsetneqq \Bbb R^2$ is closed  then $C$ is finite, so $f^{-1}C$ is finite, so $f^{-1}C$ is closed in $[0,1].$